# Enable spring datasource only for ONE test

Tags: java, spring, database, unit-testing, junit

I have a project so big in which only 3 tests in a class uses a datasource connection, and this connection is optional, so I am interested in only enable the datasource connection by spring in this test.

Looking for the Spring manual I see the option properties = {} in @SpringBootTest to enable some properties and I thought to enable here,

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {
    "spring.datasource.url=[url]",
    "spring.datasource.username=[user]",
    "spring.datasource.password=[password]",
    "spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect",
    "hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect",
    "spring.jpa.database=postgresql"})
```

But when I execute the tests with mvn clean install, in others test it returns me the error;

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "test" are currently active).
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:247) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:184) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:42) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:56) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor249.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120) [spring-boot-test-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.outputConditionEvaluationReport(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:54) [spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:47) [spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203) [surefire-booter-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155) [surefire-booter-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103) [surefire-booter-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
```

Any help?

Comment: why don't you create a separate property file using this configuration run profile with test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found and works for me it's to exclude for in the application properties 2 autoconfigures classes,

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
```

because in my case, I don't want to connect the database in the rest of the application, and in the test that I want to connect the database I added to run this test with the profile "database" and the following properties in the annotation @SpringBootTest,

```
@ActiveProfiles("database")
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {
    "spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration",
    "spring.datasource.url=[url]",
    "spring.datasource.username=[username]",
    "spring.datasource.password=[password]",
    "spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect",
    "hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect",
    "spring.jpa.database=postgresql",
    "spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.postgresql.Driver"})
```

and in the class that I want to test I have an EntityManagerFactory annotated with @Autowired, inside a @Component class. So when Spring tries to construct all the Components of the application to avoid a failure that can occur here if the databases are not enabled, I put

```
@Autowired(required = false)
```

Also, to create the bean of the connection I created a bean to create a DataSource only if the profile "database" is enabled, as I put before in the test to run that test with the profile "database",

```
@Bean
  @Profile("database")
  public DataSource dataSourceProfile(Environment env)
  {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().url(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"))
                            .driverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"))
                            .password(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"))
                            .username(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username")).build();
  }
```

So with this configuration, only this test tries to connect with the database and the rest of the test doesn't try.